# Mocking Kotlin receivers

Tags: kotlin, mocking

I was wondering - what is the best way to mock Kotlin's receivers? In more concrete terms, let's say I defined the following interfaces:

```
interface TransactionalRepository {

    fun <T> withTransaction(TransactionalOperations.() -> T)
}

interface TransactionalOperations {

    fun <T: Entity> save(entity: T)

    fun <T: Entity> load(id: UUID): T
}
```

Assuming I have some business logic using an implementation of `TransactionalRepository` like this:

```
fun decrementCounter(counterId: UUID) {
    repository.transaction {
        val entity: Counter = load(counterId)
        entity.decrement()
        save(entity)
    }
}
```

What is the best way to mock out the interactions between `TransactionalRepository` and `TransactionalOperations`?

Comment: Extension function are just static functions where the first argument is the receiver. There's no need for any specific way to mock a receiver argument vs. any regular argument.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your comment. Where is the extension function you are referring to?

Comment: There's no extension function, I've just developed the habit of viewing functions with receivers as extension function as they work very similarly. That said, imagine the function with receiver as a function with one argument (the Transactional Operations object). The implementation of TransactionalRepo will call that on its reference to that object. It's the same as invoking the function and passing in that reference.

Comment: I think I get your argument now. However, it does not solve the problem of having to mock `TransactionalRepository` with the expected behavior for `TransactionalOperations` when testing `decrementCounter`.

Comment: I'd test by creating a repository with a reference to a mock of TransactionalOperations. That is assuming the implementation of TransactionalRepository does nothing but invoke the passed in operation in withTransaction on it's reference to TransactionalOperations. I suggest to fix your sample code, since it won't compile in it's current state and provide more detail on what you're trying to achieve with those interfaces. I believe there may be a more straightforward architecture.